# Trying to overload a virtual function in a template class based on template type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, virtual-functions

I have **extra** fun shenanigans today.

I'm somewhat new to templates in C++.  Here are some classes as they currently are in my code:

```
class location2d
{
    int x, y;
}

class location3d
{
    int x, y, z;
}

template <typename T>
class myClass : public parentClass<float, T>
{
    private:

    virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
    {
        // some math stuff (this part doesn't matter)
        something = position.x + position.y;
    }

    int something;
};
```

Right now this is hardcoded to location2d.  I need myFunction() to have different behavior if location3d is passed in.  For example:

```
virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
{
    something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
}
```

I've read up on template specialization, but this gets tricky because myFunction() is overriding a virtual function in the base class.  It's my understanding we can't specialize a virtual function.  I tried anyway.  It hated it.

My second idea was to type check the template and just call separate helpers:

```
virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
{
    if (std::is_same<T, location3d) {myFunction3(position);}
    else {myFunction2(position);}
}

void myFunction2 (T position) const
{
    something = position.x + position.y;
}

void myFunction3 (T position) const
{
    something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler throws on "location2d does not contain member 'z'", which is absolutely true.  However, myFunction3() wouldn't be called unless z existed.

Next I tried specifically casting so that T would no longer be ambiguous:

```
virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
{
    if (std::is_same<T, location3d>::value) {myFunction3((location3d)position);}
    else {myFunction2((location2d)position);}
}
```

"'type cast': cannot convert from 'T' to 'location3'".

Final idea:
Since the helper functions aren't virtual, maybe I can just specialize those two.

```
virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
{
    if (std::is_same<T, location3d>::value) {mySecondFunction<location3d>(position);}
    else {mySecondFunction<location2d>(position);}
}

template<>
void mySecondFunction<location2d> (location2d position) const {}

template<>
void mySecondFunction<location3d> (location3d position) const {}
```

I'm not sure if I did that wrong, but it threw tons of syntax errors that I don't know how to fix.

At the end of the day, all I want is for myFunction()'s behavior to change based on whether 'z' exists or not, and I don't have a preference how it's done.  I feel like I must be missing something simple here.

Comment: Can you use c++17? Also, please make a [mre] What is `parentClass`?

Comment: You'll need a `constexpr if` or a template specialization. One of the branches still tries to compile, while the other one would fit your needs. `std::enable_if` is another option.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible to "specialize a virtual function"? First off: You specialize the class not the function itself in this case, which is important here. You can do whatever you want in your specialization, which includes overriding function from a parent class. A specialization is not related to the "base template" in any way; its like a completely different class that gets used if your template parameter matches the parameter you specialized for.

Comment: If its inconvenient for you to replace the whole class and you only want to change a single function you can either put common code in yet another (intermidiate) base class or you can use `constexpr if` from C++17 onwards as @πάνταῥεῖ has already pointed out. The old way was to use `std::enable_if` or SFINAE manually but `constexpr if` is much more convenient.

Comment: Also you seem to have a major missunderstnading here: `T` is a template parameter of `myClass` and `myClass<T>::myFunction` is not a *function template*. Its just like any other method of `myClass`. Thus it is also not possible to specialize `myClass<T>::myFunction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to do type checking is valid, but your approaches need a little more work to help the compiler.

If you are using C++17 or later, use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) with [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class myClass : public parentClass<float, T>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, location3d>) {
            something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
        }
        else {
            something = position.x + position.y;
        }
    }

    int something;
};
```

The compiler will evaluate the `if constexpr` completely at compile-time and eliminate the unused branch in the final runtime code, thus producing different code for each instantiation of `myClass<T>`, eg:

```cpp
class myClass<location2d> : public parentClass<float, location2d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location2d position) const override final
    {
        something = position.x + position.y;
    }

    int something;
};

class myClass<location3d> : public parentClass<float, location3d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location3d position) const override final
    {
        something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
    }

    int something;
};
```

If using C++17 or later is not an option for you, then you can use `reinterpret_cast` instead, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class myClass : public parentClass<float, T>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
    {
        if (std::is_same<T, location3d>::value) {
            // if T is NOT location3d then accessing position.z as-is
            // will fail to compile if T::z is missing, hence the cast.
            // Since this branch is executed only when T is location3d,
            // the cast in this branch is redundant but harmless. But
            // this branch is still compiled even when T is NOT loction3d...
            something = position.x + position.y + reinterpret_cast<location3d&>(position).z;
        }
        else {
            // no cast is needed here since location2d and location3d
            // both have x and y fields...
            something = position.x + position.y;
        }
    }

    int something;
};
```

Without the cast, the compiler would produce code like the following for each instantiation of `myClass<T>`:

```cpp
class myClass<location2d> : public parentClass<float, location2d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location2d position) const override final
    {
        if (false) {
            something = position.x + position.y + position.z; // ERROR! location2d::z does not exist...
        }
        else {
            something = position.x + position.y; // OK
        }
    }

    int something;
};

class myClass<location3d> : public parentClass<float, location3d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location3d position) const override final
    {
        if (true) {
            something = position.x + position.y + position.z; // OK
        }
        else {
            something = position.x + position.y; // OK
        }
    }

    int something;
};
```

The same issue happens when passing `position` to non-template member methods instead, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class myClass : public parentClass<float, T>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
    {
        if (std::is_same<T, location3d) {
            // if T is NOT location3d, passing position as-is to myFunction3()
            // would fail to compile, hence the cast. Since this branch is
            // executed only when T is location3d, the cast in this branch
            // is redundant but harmless. But this branch is still compiled
            // even when T is NOT loction3d...
            myFunction3(reinterpret_cast<location3d&>(position));
        }
        else {
            // if T is NOT location2d, passing position as-is to myFunction2()
            // would fail to compile, hence the cast. Since this branch is
            // executed only when T is location2d, the cast in this branch
            // is redundant but harmless. But this branch is still compiled
            // even when T is NOT location2d...
            myFunction2(reinterpret_cast<location2d>(position));
        }
    }

    void myFunction2 (location2d position)
    {
        something = position.x + position.y;
    }

    void myFunction3 (location3d position)
    {
        something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
    }

    int something;
};
```

Without the casts, the compiler would produce code like the following for each instantiation of `myClass<T>`:

```cpp
class myClass<location2d> : public parentClass<float, location2d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location2d position) const override final
    {
        if (false) {
            myFunction3(position); // ERROR! can't convert from location2d to location3d
        }
        else {
            myFunction2(position); // OK
        }
    }

    void myFunction2 (location2d position)
    {
        something = position.x + position.y;
    }

    void myFunction3 (location3d position)
    {
        something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
    }

    int something;
};

class myClass<location3d> : public parentClass<float, location3d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location3d position) const override final
    {
        if (true) {
            myFunction3(position); // OK
        }
        else {
            myFunction2(position); // ERROR! can't convert from location3d to location2d
        }
    }

    void myFunction2 (location2d position)
    {
        something = position.x + position.y;
    }

    void myFunction3 (location3d position)
    {
        something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
    }

    int something;
};
```

That being said, another option would be to use template specialization, then no funky casts are needed at all, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
int add_them_up(T) { return 0; }

template<>
int add_them_up<location2d>(location2d position)
{
    return position.x + position.y;
}

template<>
int add_them_up<location3d>(location3d position)
{
    return position.x + position.y + position.z;
}

template <typename T>
class myClass : public parentClass<float, T>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (T position) const override final
    {
        something = add_them_up<T>(position);
    }

    int something;
};
```

The compiler would produce code like the following for each instantiation of `myClass<T>`:

```cpp
int add_them_up<location2d>(location2d position)
{
    return position.x + position.y;
}

int add_them_up<location3d>(location3d position)
{
    return position.x + position.y + position.z;
}

class myClass<location2d> : public parentClass<float, location2d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location2d position) const override final
    {
        something = add_them_up<location2d>(position);
    }

    int something;
};

class myClass<location3d> : public parentClass<float, location3d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location3d position) const override final
    {
        something = add_them_up<location3d>(position);
    }

    int something;
};
```

Which, after the compiler inlines the specialized functions at the call sites, would look *very familiar* <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: *<cough>* the C++17 `if constexpr` output !</sup>

```cpp
class myClass<location2d> : public parentClass<float, location2d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location2d position) const override final
    {
        something = position.x + position.y;
    }

    int something;
};

class myClass<location3d> : public parentClass<float, location3d>
{
private:
    virtual void myFunction (location3d position) const override final
    {
        something = position.x + position.y + position.z;
    }

    int something;
};
```

Comment: A fantastic and detailed answer!  I didn't know about constexpr, so that's half the battle.  The other half is lasers.  I'll keep those other suggestions in mind for the future.  Thanks!